# How to get the start and end positions of a drag gesture in JetpackCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get the start and end positions of a drag in Jetpack Compose. To this end I used the following code. But the PointerInputChange functions don't behave as expected on the documentation. Since control never enter those if blocks. What am I doing wrong/Is there another way to get the start/end positions?

```
.pointerInput(key1 = Unit) {
        detectDragGestures(
            onDrag = {change, dragAmount ->
                //get the start position
                if(change.changedToDownIgnoreConsumed()) {
                    Log.d("User Input", "Drag start @ ${change.position}")
                }
                //get the end postion
                if(change.changedToUpIgnoreConsumed()) {
                    Log.d("User Input", "Drag end @ ${change.position}")
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current implementation probably is that you are executing your `if` statements within the wrong callback. The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputScope).detectDragGestures(kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function2)) contains the following synopsis for `detectDragGestures`:

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectDragGestures(
    onDragStart: (Offset) -> Unit = { },
    onDragEnd: () -> Unit = { },
    onDragCancel: () -> Unit = { },
    onDrag: (change: PointerInputChange, dragAmount: Offset) -> Unit ): Unit
```

As you can see, there are dedicated callbacks for `onDragStart` and `onDragEnd`. So my guess is, `onDrag` is not called at the start and the end, and thus the conditions `change.changedToDownIgnoreConsumed()` and `change.changedToUpIgnoreConsumed()` always are false.

Try to modify your code like below and report back if that resolves the issue:

```
var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

// Composable...

.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(
        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
            change.consume()
            offsetX += dragAmount.x
            offsetY += dragAmount.y
        },
        onDragStart = { offset -> 
            offsetX = offset.x
            offsetY = offset.y
            Log.d("User Input", "Drag start @ ${offsetX}, ${offsetY}") 
        },
        onDragEnd = { Log.d("User Input", "Drag end @ ${offsetX}, ${offsetY}") },
        onDragCancel = { Log.d("User Input", "Drag end @ ${offsetX}, ${offsetY}") }
    )
}
```